# Update Database if Workflow Completes/Fails

Tags: java, spring, callback, microservices, conductor

I have a spring micro-service that on any CRUD endpoint updates an entity then registers a workflow to a orchestration system (Netflix conductor). This workflow is responsible for converting the entities to a specific config format & applying the configuration to some arbitrary devices.

The issue is if the workflow fails, the first micro-service's database isn't accurate. (entity in an updated state, but the configuration failed to apply)

Is the proper design to implement a callback to the service? I could do this as a task at the end of the workflow. How would I "store" the database changes to be committed/invalidated after the callback? (obviously can't be a long running transaction)